# How to Display Exception In Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller, grails-validation

a have a problem with my code. how can i handle an error from service to my gsp? i tried it with render from service or controller, Validation error occured during call to save(): - Field error in object 'talent.CandidateProfile' on field 'core.db_email': rejected value []; codes with full exception trace. my sources:

```
 def create() {
        [candidateProfileInstance: new CandidateProfile(params)]
    }

    def save() {
        def candidateProfileInstance = new CandidateProfile(params)
        if (!candidateProfileInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "create", model: [candidateProfileInstance: candidateProfileInstance])
            return
        }

        flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'candidateProfile.label', default: 'CandidateProfile'), candidateProfileInstance.id])
        redirect(action: "show", id: candidateProfileInstance.id)
    }
```

My .gsp page code

```
<div class="full-filed">
            <h3>Email Address:</h3>
        </div>
        <div    class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: candidateProfileInstance, field: 'core.db_email', 'error')} ">
            <label for="core.db_email" class="error_message"> <g:message
                    code="candidateProfile.core.db_email.label" default="Dbemail" />
            </label>
        </div>
        <g:textField name="core.db_email" value="" class="loginTxtBox" placeholder="Email Address" />
```

**i want just show to user an error, but not full exception trace**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

form your config.grooyPage

//grails.gorm.failOnError = true

just comment to this line...SO it will display your Custom Error